# Make update loop in sync with music and notes in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to make some notes appearing when the music hits a certain time in Phaser, but when I log the "hit times" in the console, it only show up sometimes.

I have an object of "notes", the key being the time I expect the note to show :

```
{
  1377: {
    jam: 1,
    duration: 0.40
  }
}
```

with 1464 notes.

But, in the update loop, if I do something like this :

```
update () {
  if (music && music.currentTime) {
    if (notes[music.currentTime]) {
      console.log('notes[music.currentTime].jam', notes[music.currentTime].jam)
    }
  }
}
```

It logs only some of the notes, randomly.

Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because `music.currentTime` is incrementing by ~16 ms on each update, so it can skip specific time keys from your `notes` object. Other than that I believe that the time can also be a floating point value, so it won't exactly match your keys in the `notes` variable.

An alternate way to implement what you want would be to change format of the `notes` variable to an array so it could be accessed later in a different manner:

```js
var notes = [    
    ...
    {'start': 1377, 'jam': 1, 'duration': 0.40},
    {'start': 2456, 'jam': 1, 'duration': 0.30},
    ...
];

// Index of the first note that will be played.
// Will be incremented by 1 or more with some update() calls,
// depending on the time that passed.
var nextNote = 0;

function update() {
    // Process all notes that are now in the past
    // compared to the current time of the playing music,
    // but skip notes that have been already played before.
    while (music && nextNote < notes.length && notes[nextNote].start <= music.currentTime) {
        console.log(notes[nextNote]);
        nextNote += 1;
    }
}
```

For this method to work, the `notes` array must hold start times in an ascending order.

Comment: It doesn't work. Even something like this : `var time = Math.floor(music.currentTime)
      if (time === 1543) {
        console.log('time', time)
      }` never trigger the `console.log`

Comment: Yes, now actually I think the `currentTime` property can skip by several milliseconds, so it can be for example less than 1543 and on the next update it will be bigger than 1543. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to work (you just forgot the `.start` in `notes[lastNote] <= music.currentTime`).

Thank you for your answer :)